# Google sheets Function myfunction() explained?

Tags: google-apps-script

What does the () on the function do. I have seen people put letters in there or words, but I don’t understand the purpose or what that does.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis serves as a way to actually call (execute) the function with the name preceding the parenthesis. You should perhaps go through some programming lessons. Try starting here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide